# special characters in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I was making a search for project i was working on. when someone search for a term it will be save in a MySQL database. im using `mysql_real_escape_string` to escape special characters but still special characters are saving in the database for a example

Don't become Don\'t

then i tried `htmlspecialchars` it is still the same. i even change the db to `utf8_general_ci` also i tried all togather.

here is the code

```
$addSearch = htmlspecialchars($search);
$addSearch1 = mysql_real_escape_string($addSearch);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO search (term) VALUES('$addSearch1') ") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

can anyone tell me a solution for this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried replace()?

Comment: Use mysqli_* instead of mysql_*

Comment: what exactly are you wanting mysql to do? Do you want my sql to NOT save special characters in the database so instead of don\'t it stores dont ? As in: what problem are you trying to solve? If you want single quotes to be stored in the db they MUST be stored as escaped \'  Maybe your question is about geting them back out frm the DB. Again: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this....

```
$height='aA1`';
$value=preg_replace("/[^\`a-z,. \'\-\d]/i", "", $height);
$value=mysql_real_escape_string($value);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` SET `column`='$value'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex for removing special characters from string

```
$addSearch = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $search);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO search (term) VALUES('$addSearch') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

and use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead of `mysql` because it is deprecated and can be removed in future.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise checking your PHP config (php.ini) to see if "Magic Quotes" are enabled. And if so, turn them off & restart your web service. More [info here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

You can alternatively use this in an `.htaccess` file if you cannot edit `php.ini`:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are many way to do this. Maybe there is something wrong that you couldn't see.

```
$str = addslashes($str);
$str = addcslashes($str, "'\"");
$str = str_replace(array("'", '"'), array("\\'", '\\"'), $str);
$str = preg_replace("~([\"'])~", "\\\\1", $str);
```